# Do parallel lines form a triangle?

Tags: soft-question, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

One definition of a triangle reads 'a polygon with 3 vertices and 3 edges' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle). It occurred to me recently that an axiomatic and more information-rich definition might be more along the lines of 'the intersection of the interiors of two distinct angles', where the interior of an angle (taken from Greenburg's 'Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry) is 'Given an angle $\angle CAB$ define a point D to be in the interior of $\angle CAB$ if D is on the same side of $\overline{AC}$ as B and if D is also on the same side of $\overline{AB} $ as C. (Thus, the interior of an angle is the
intersection of two half-planes)'. I believe this is a neutral geometry definition.
Intriguingly to me, not necessarily in neutral geometry, if one considers 'straight angles' as legitimate (side question, "do we?"), this would for example mean that the region enclosed by two parallels would technically be a triangle. 
So, I guess there are at least a couple questions here. In neutral geometry,
Is a straight angle ($\pi$ radians if you like, or $\angle ABC$, where A*B*C e.g. B is between A and C), an angle just like any other angle? Is the region between parallel lines (not necessarily neutral geometry here) a triangle? Is the area defined and is it non-zero, zero, or infinite?

Comment: One could certainly concoct, say, a parameterized trio of lines that "usually" intersect in three points and yield a standard triangle; and, then, it's possible that the lines become parallel at some values of the parameter. Whether this leads one to accept parallel-sided figures as "triangles" would be largely a matter of semantics and context. Maybe it makes sense, maybe not. (The situation is not-unlike how it sometimes helps to treat lines as [generalized circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle).) I'd expect the area to be infinite (unless, perhaps, the lines coincide).

Comment: What does "axiomatic" mean when applied to a definition? As stated, any quadrilateral also meets your definition. To restrict it to triangles only, you have to specify that the two angles share a side. And two distinct parallel straight angles does not meet that restriction. So a pair of parallel lines can be considered an infinite quadrilateral, not an infinite triangle. Finally, if one definition is "more information rich" than another, then its definition necessarily is more restrictive than the other. To be equivalent, the information content must be the same.